# addingand using marker variable with geoJsonData and markercluster with leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markerclusterer

I've been searching for hours and hours now, and i'm still stuck. I have a feeling it is something easy/stupid i'm missing.

I am using the example of markercluster from GitHub. I have 2 different markers (simply 2 different colors) that i would like to show which i would defined in the json format.
I have followed guide from leaflet site to define different markers.
I added my variable to the json part, but i can not figure out how to make the map load the different markers. It's either giving me no map or error; or it still uses the default blue marker.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var geoJsonData = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"1", "properties": { "address": "2","marker": "cmIcon"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2209316333,-37.8210922667 ] } },
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"2", "properties": { "address": "151","marker": "otherIcon" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2238417833,-37.80975435   ] } },
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"3", "properties": { "address": "21","marker": "cmIcon"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2169955667,-37.818193     ] } },
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"4", "properties": { "address": "14","marker": "otherIcon"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2240856667,-37.8216963    ] } },
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"5", "properties": { "address": "38B","marker": "cmIcon" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2196982333,-37.8188702167 ] } },
                { "type": "Feature", "id":"6", "properties": { "address": "38","marker": "otherIcon"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2209942   ,-37.8192782833 ] } }
            ]
        };

        var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
            key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
        });

        var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
                shadowUrl: 'marker/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize:     [32, 32],
                shadowSize:   [36, 20],
                iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
                shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
            }
        });

        var cmIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'marker/marker-cm.png'}),
            otherIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'marker/marker-others.png'});

        var map = L.map('map')
                .addLayer(cloudmade);

        var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

        var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.address);
            }
        });
        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

        map.addLayer(markers);
        map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

        function onLocationFound(e) {
                    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

                    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
                        .bindPopup("Vous etes ici").openPopup();

                    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
                }

                function onLocationError(e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }

                map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
                map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

                map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
    </script>
```

I suspect that i need to tell leaflet to get the marker variable, probably in

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.address);
            }
        });
```

but i cannot make it work.

i even tried as suggested some where else:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.address),
layer.setIcon(feature.properties.marker);
            }
        });
```

i'm still getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object cmIcon has no method 'createIcon'

does anybody have an idea on how to do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the MarkerClusterGroup how to create the icon.  The [marker cluster docs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) show an example with a DivIcon like this:

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>' });
    }
});
```

You can use your custom icon instead like this:

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        // decide which icon you want to use
        return (cluster.getChildCount() > 10) ? cmIcon : otherIcon;
    }
});
```